# Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I learning redux by following some tutorial. Here I am getting an error

> Object(...) is not a function

in this line

```
export default connect(null, { fetchPosts } )(Posts);
```

of the following container

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/postActions.js';

class Posts extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }
  render() {
    const postItems = this.state.posts.map(el => {
      return (
        <div key={el.id}>
        <h3>{el.title} </h3>
        <p>{el.body} </p>
        </div>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div>
      <h1> Posts </h1>
      {postItems}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default connect(null, { fetchPosts } )(Posts);
```

Ps: I know it will also throw the map error but I am not worried about it at the moment.

Since it says **Object(...) is not a function** and marks the line export, the only object we have inside export is the fetchPosts which looks like this (it is an action function)

```
import { FETCH_POST, NEW_POST } from './type.js'
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchPosts = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then((response) => dispatch({
      type: FETCH_POST,
      payload: response
    }))
  }

}
```

Since I am not sure the relevant code for the same, the fetchPosts dispatches an acton to the following reducer

```
    import { FETCH_POST, NEW_POST } from '../actions/type.js'
const initialState = {
  items: [],
  item: {}
}
    export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload
      }
      default:
        return state
  }

}
```

Which is later combined using combineReducers in our rootreducer.js file (which is then imported to store.js where we create store)

**Can Anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and How can we fix it?**

Comment: You are importing `connect` from react. It should be `react-redux`. Also, do you use something like redux-thunk?

Comment: @devserkan That fixed it. Also, If you can answer one more question related to this post (since I can't ask another question for next 90 minutes). How can the instructor do `this.props.fetchPosts();` in componentDidMount, i.e props go from parent to child and I think that fetchPosts is a child?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: 'props' are properties which flow from parent component to child component (one directional), Since we are importing `fetchPosts` it will happen to be a child? so how can the instructor do something like this `class Posts extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  } ` (referring the first snippet of code shared in connection.

Comment: fetchPosts is not a child, it is an action creator. Actually it is returning a function and with this function you are dispatching an action. This is why I asked about redux-thunk. So, it is not a normal action creator, you need something like redux-thunk. Action creators dispatch an action and this action goes through related reducer, then this reducer updates your state. This is a broad topic. Go examine some more tutorials about Redux and if you don't get it feel free to ask a question about it. I will give an answer about the import problem.

Comment: @devserkan I went through couple of articles through couple of articles but had no luck, All they says is something like `hange this.fetchData() in componentDidMount() to this.props.fetchData().
Change this.state.X to this.props.X for .hasErrored, .isLoading and .items.` I will ask it as a separate question in few minutes :) 
Link for the above article: https://codepen.io/stowball/post/a-dummy-s-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react
I will ask this as a separate question shortly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174573/discussion-between-kuchbhi-and-devserkan).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React does not have a named `connect` export, it belongs to `react-redux`. So, you should import it like that:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
```